# jquery iButton plugin causing elements to be not clickable in iOS 6

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-plugins, checkbox, ios6

Working fine in iOS 5 and below the [jQuery iButton plugin](http://www.givainc.com/labs/ibutton_jquery_plugin.htm) does still work in iOS 6 but causing multiple other Elements on the page to no longer clickable.
(happens in chrome as well as in safari on the iPad)

When touch-holding on those Elements they don't get focussed, but their parent Element.

This seems not to be related with the jQuery version used.

Does anyone know of a possible fix for this?

Or has anyone a suggestion for an alternative library for iOS-style-on/off-buttons.
(should also support touch/swipe etc)

*as we're working on some closed backend-app, posting code examples is unfortunately not possible.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

found the solution.

replace this:

```
$(document).bind("mouseup.iButton_" + id + " touchend.iButton_" + id, function(e) {
```

with this:

```
$(document).delegate(".ibutton-container","mouseup.iButton_" + id + " touchend.iButton_" + id, function(e) {
```

in the **ibutton** plugin.

(in jquery versions greater than 1.7 you should use `on()` instead of `delegate()` )

Comment: Finally, the answer I've been searching for! I should have guessed it was a plugin mucking things up.

Comment: Really it works. The line 256 of js.
But in jquery 1.7.1, on() doesn't work, use delegate().

Comment: still default checked , but at least stopped blocking elements (Samsung Galaxy Note2)

Answer (score 3):

This may save you a few seconds of googling. I implemented the fix suggested above, for jQuery version 1.8.3 (> 1.7) using the .on-method. Tested to work on **iOS 6.0.1**:

```
$(document).on("mouseup.iButton_" + id + " touchend.iButton_" + id, ".ibutton-container", function(e) {
```